# how do I loop servo motor and stop and loop again?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I bought mg995 servo motor but it seems controlling is different from the mg90 because it is digital.

What I want to do is spinning mg995 loop, stops when I press ctrl+c and starts loop again when I press the enter. the code is below but it won't loop again after servo1.stop()

```
from cmath import inf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO     
from time import sleep      


################# -----------------------------
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)      

servo1_pin = 18                  

GPIO.setup(servo1_pin, GPIO.OUT)   
servo1 = GPIO.PWM(servo1_pin, 50)  
servo1.start(0)  


servo_min_duty = 3               
servo_max_duty = 12             


def set_servo_degree(servo_num, degree):
    if degree > 180:
        degree = 180
    elif degree < 0:
        degree = 0

    duty = servo_min_duty+(degree*(servo_max_duty-servo_min_duty)/180.0)
    if servo_num == 1:
        servo1.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)



#################-------------------------------


try:
  while True:
    set_servo_degree(1, 0)
    
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
  servo1.stop() # after servo stops, it won't start again.
  print("should be end")
  pass

go_button = input('go? press enter!')
if go_button == "":
   ## after press the enter, starts loop again. 
    try:
      while True:
        set_servo_degree(1, 0)
    
else:
    break()


sleep(2)                           
GPIO.cleanup()
```

thank you!

Comment: It looks like you never call `server1.start` after calling `servo1.stop`?

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop should be outside of the `set_servo_degree` function.

The modified part of your code is as below

```
servo_num = 1
servo_deg = 0

while True:
    try:
        set_servo_degree(servo_num, servo_deg)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        servo1.stop()
        go_button = input('go? press enter!')
        if go_button == "":
            set_servo_degree(servo_num, servo_deg)
        else:
            break

sleep(2)
GPIO.cleanup()
```